# Razor parser isn't parsing?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
    <script>
    function check() {
        var Not = false;
        //Doing something...
        if (Not) {
            @ViewBag.IsTrue = false;  //This line appears like    = false
        }
        else{
            @ViewBag.IsTrue = true; //This line appears like    = false too
        }
</script>
```

Can somebody explain me what is happening?
I'm using .NET 4.6 and MVC 5.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're confusing Javascript code with Razor code.  You can't do that.

Comment: It means that `@ViewBag.IsTrue` is resolving to nothing when the Razor code is evaluated **on the server** - long before the JavaScript runs.

Comment: @SLaks is there any way to do this?

Comment: @DimoChanev: No; it doesn't even make sense.  You need to understand the difference between _client-side_ code and _server-side_ code.

Comment: How can you do _what_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor syntax parser conflict.

`@ViewBag.IsTrue` is not a correct variable in javascript.
But execution is actually correct.

If you mind，may be using the code like following:

```
<script>
    function check() {
        var Not = false;
        //Doing something...
        if (Not) {
            window["@ViewBag.IsTrue"] = false;
        }
        else{
            window["@ViewBag.IsTrue"] = true;
        }
</script>
```

to make it working well.